# Using data-* like a text in img

Tags: html, css

I have this

```
<div class="item" data-name="Lorem ipsum"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350" alt="Lorem"></div>
<div class="item" data-name="Lorem ipsum 2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350" alt="Lorem"></div>
```

What I want:

I want to position text from data-name values over the top of the image elements. I tried to define

```
.item[display-name] {
content:'data-name';
display:block;
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: what are you trying to do ? This does not look right at all. Please tell us what is expected output

Comment: I want to have that data-name values like text in image. @AlwaysHelping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No quotes. Missing the attr keyword.
Your not putting this :before or :after

```
/* <div data-line="1"></div> */

div[data-line]:after { 
    content: attr(data-line); /* no quotes around attribute name! */
}
```

Pulled from these examples.
https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr

Answer (score 2):

Working Example based on your codes:

```css
.item[data-name]::after {
  content: attr(data-name);
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" data-name="Lorem ipsum 2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350" alt="Lorem"></div>
```